# Fetching video files using multer and AJAX in Node.js backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, multer

I am trying to upload a video file to Mongo DB. I am using EJS in the front-end to select the video file. After that, i am using an ajax request as given below, to pass the form data to the back-end.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/savepost',
        type: 'post',
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: 'json',
})
```

The /savepost logic is give as below. Here console.log(file) fetches an "undefined" value for video files while it works well with image files. Any help on uploading video file using multer is much appreciated.

```
router.post('/savepost',upload.single('upload'),function(req,res,next) {
    var body = req.body.body;
    var file = req.file;
    console.log(file);
    var userdata = {userID: req.user._id, fullname: req.user.fullname, image: req.user.image};
    if(file){
    cloudinary.uploader.upload("./public/images/posts/" + file.filename, function (result) {
        file.filename = result.secure_url;
        async.waterfall([
            function (callback) {
                var newPost = new Post();
                newPost.body = body.trim();
                newPost.image = file.filename;
                newPost.owner = userdata;
                newPost.save((err, data) => {
                    if (err) res.send({msg: "Something went wrong", success: false});
                    if (data) callback(null, data);
                });
            },
            function (data, callback) {
                User.findOneAndUpdate(
                    {_id: req.user._id},
                    {
                        $push:
                            {
                                posts: {
                                    post: data._id,
                                    body: data.body,
                                    image: data.image
                                }
                            }
                    },
                    (err, user) => {
                        if (err) res.send({msg: "Something went wrong", success: false});
                        if (user) res.send({msg: "Data Saved", post: data, success: true});
                    }
                );
            }
        ]);
    });
}
```

Comment: inspect the request and check ajax is sending data from client side or not.

Comment: console.log(file) for images is giving a result having the details of the file. But when i am trying upload video file then it fails.